# MS Access ODBC Connection error - "cannot define field more than once"

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

Does anybody have some insight on why the following error "cannot define field more than once" comes up in ms access when connecting MySQL tables via ODBC? The only thing I can think of is that I have multiple tables with the same name across other schemas, which may throw things off, but it's pretty important to me to not change a bunch of table names. Thoughts?

Also for reference, I exported to excel one of these problem tables and tried importing to access via excel. The import via excel worked totally fine, which eliminates the possibility of header truncation or duplicates.

Comment: can it be related to the column name lengths? although MsAccess allows 64 chars in an MsAccess table's column, the driver you use to connect to MySQL (ODBC driver for MySQL?) may have a shorter limit truncating longer ones; what is the longest column name in the tables causing this error?

Comment: Just did a quick check, and I'm going to also rule that out as a possibility. Seems to be more related to multiple tables under separate schemas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also make sure that some special characters in the table/column names are converted by Access, and two different ones may become the same. Do you have any special characters in your table/column names (anything outside letters, numbers, underscore, and space)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be that easy. It's definitely not a character length, type or general truncation issue as there's multiple tables that don't connect in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.  [see this link.](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106277)  It indicates that v8.0.26 of the MySQL ODBC connector works.  I am using 8.0.25 and it works for me.  Apparently there's an 8.0.29 forthcoming that should fix it.

Comment: Perfect. I too have now downgraded. Works like a charm again.